# table game has no column named title: , while compiling: INSERT INTO game(title, rating, info) VALUES (?, ?, ?);

Tags: android

I am getting an error while trying to insert an item into my database.

This is what Logcat reads:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException table game has no column named title: , while compiling: INSERT INTO game(title, rating, info)  VALUES (?, ?, ?);
```

This is my database manager:

```
package com.herring.android.finalproject;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class GameDataBaseManager {

    private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDb;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "data";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;  
    private final Context mCtx;
    private static final String GAME_TABLE_NAME = "game";
    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
    public static final String KEY_BODY = "info";
    public static final String KEY_RATING = "rating";
    private static final String GAME_TABLE_CREATE = "create table " + GAME_TABLE_NAME + " ( " + 
            KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + 
            KEY_TITLE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            KEY_BODY + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + 
            KEY_RATING + " NUM NOT NULL );";


    public GameDataBaseManager(Context ctx)
    {
        this.mCtx = ctx;
    }


    public long addRow(String rowStringOne, String rowStringTwo, float rating)
    {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_TITLE, rowStringOne);
        values.put(KEY_BODY, rowStringTwo);
        values.put(KEY_RATING, rating);
        return mDb.insert(GAME_TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    }
    public void deleteRow(long rowID)
    {
        try
        {
            mDb.delete(GAME_TABLE_NAME, KEY_ROWID + " = " + rowID, null);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("DB ERROR", e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public GameDataBaseManager open() throws android.database.SQLException
    {
        mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
        mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close()
    {
        mDbHelper.close();
    }

    public Cursor getAllGames()
    {
        return mDb.query(GAME_TABLE_NAME, null, null,
                null, null, null, null);
    }

    public Cursor fetchGame(long rowId) throws SQLException
    {
        Cursor mCursor = mDb.query(true, GAME_TABLE_NAME, new String[]{KEY_ROWID, KEY_TITLE, KEY_BODY, KEY_RATING}, 
                KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null, null, null, null, null);
        if(mCursor != null)
        {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;
    }

    public boolean updateDb(long rowId, String title, String body, String rating)
    {
        ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
        args.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
        args.put(KEY_BODY, body);
        args.put(KEY_RATING, rating);

        return mDb.update(GAME_TABLE_NAME, args, KEY_ROWID + " = " + rowId, null) > 0;
    }

    public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL(GAME_TABLE_CREATE);

        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        }
    }
}
```

Here is the Activity where I try to insert the item:

```
package com.herring.android.finalproject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;

public class TopRatedActivity extends Activity {
    private Cursor gamesCursor;
    private ListView lv;
    private GameDataBaseManager mDbHelper;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mDbHelper = new GameDataBaseManager(this);
        mDbHelper.open();
        mDbHelper.addRow("Game", "Info", 0);
        setContentView(R.layout.toprated);
        fillData();

    }
    private void fillData()
    {
        gamesCursor = mDbHelper.getAllGames();
        startManagingCursor(gamesCursor);
        String[] from = new String[]{GameDataBaseManager.KEY_TITLE};
        int[] to = new int[]{R.id.text1};
        SimpleCursorAdapter games = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.toprateditem, gamesCursor, from, to);
        lv.setAdapter(games);
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is this issue on emulator (or) on phone?

Comment: I am running this on an emulator.

Comment: It seems your query looks ok (Unless I missed something), can you completly uninstall app from emulator and try again?

Comment: I agree with @thinksteep it's seems ok about code and query...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a table named "game" in your database. But it doesn't have a column called "title". You could try deleting the entire database and creating it again.

Comment: I thought I added it into GAME_TABLE_CREATE as KEY_TITLE.  Is that wrong?

Comment: uninstall app ... i bet that you've created this table without this column and then added it in code ... but db on emulator/device was not changed (you didn't change DATABASE_VERSION )(well, even if you change it it will not work coz your onUpgrade method is empty, normally we drop old tables and recreate here or we can do ALTER table or whatever)